# modify this code to print elements that differ a x number from previous position

Tags: perl

I wrote this code to find substrings every x elements:

```
print "enter file path\n";
$letters = <>;
chomp ($letters);

$sequence = "";

open (LETTERS, $letters) or die "error opening\n";

print "how many letters at a shot\n";
$number = <>;
chomp ($number);

$size = length $sequence;
chomp ($size);


for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    $test = substr ($sequence, $i, $number);
    print "> Test $i\n";
    print "$test\n";

    if ($i >= $size - $number) {
    last;
    }

    }
```

so if I open a file with this string and choose x = 3:

```
abcdefg
```

I get this result:

```
> Test 0 abc
> Test 1 bcd
> Test 2 cde
> Test 3 def
> Test 4 efg
```

Each substring differs from one position from the previous substring, I'd like to be able to control this number and dislocate the substring by 2 for example. So the result would be:

```
> Test 0 abc
> Test 2 cde
> Test 4 efg
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: @nmf - When you get your variables named appropriately, if you are going to use substr() you should check for overflow _before_ you call it, otherwise if $i + $number exceed the last character in the string, it will just get up to the last character. Put your overflow as the first expression in the loop. I.e. `last if ( ($i+$number) >= $len );` Then do the step increment within the for construct `for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i+=$step)`. I removed the _regex_ tag because it was never necessary. Also removed my post as it was regex solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
...
$step = <>;
...
```

And change:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
```

to

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i+=$step) {
```

Answer (score 0):

`for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i += 2) {`